# no appropriate default constructor available initialising ostream pointer

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to create a logging class like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class logstream : public std::ostream
{
public:
  logstream() : os(&std::cout), file_(false) {}  // line 7

  logstream(const char* filename) : os(new std::ofstream("file.txt")), file_(true) {
    // open file - raise exception if cannot open

  }

  ~logstream() {
     // check if file and if so close
    if(file_) {
      os->close();
      delete os;
    }      
  }

private:
  std::ostream* os;
  bool file_;
};
```

But I get this error on line 7:

```
error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

And same error on line 9:

```
error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

I also need to fix this error on the os->close line:

```
error C2039: 'close' : is not a member of 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

Any ideas how to fix these compile errors?

UPDATE

So I can either do it like this:

```
class logstream 
{
public:
  logstream() : os(&std::cout), file_(false) {}

  logstream(const char* filename) : os(new std::ofstream("file.txt")), file_(true) {
    // open file - raise exception if cannot open

  }

  ~logstream() {
     // check if file and if so close
    if(file_) {
      static_cast<std::ofstream*>(os)->close();
      delete os;
    }      
  }

private:
  std::ostream* os;
  bool file_;
};
```

With an internal ostream object.  Or I can inherit from ostream and remove the internal ostream ptr.  But how would I write my constructor for inherited version?

I get errors on this version:

```
class logstream2 : public std::ostream
{
public:
  logstream2() : std::ostream(std::cout) {}

  logstream2(const char* filename) : std::ostream(std::ofstream("file.txt")) {
    // open file - raise exception if cannot open - check state of stream

  }

  ~logstream2() {
    // not sure if I need this     
  }
};
```

Errors:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\ios(151) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

This is what I ended up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class logstream
{
public:
  logstream() : os(&std::cout), file_(false) {}

  logstream(const char* filename) : os(new std::ofstream(filename)), file_(true) {
    // open file - raise exception if cannot open - TODO
  }

  ~logstream() {
     // check if file and if so close
    if(file_) {
      static_cast<std::ofstream*>(os)->close();
      delete os;
    }      
  }

  template<typename T>
  std::ostream& operator<<(const T& o) {
    return *os << o;
  }

private:
  std::ostream* os;
  bool file_;
};


int main () {
  logstream log("logtest.txt");
  log << "Hi Guys!\n";
  log << "number: " << 3 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class logstream
{
public:
    logstream() : os(new std::ostream(std::cout.rdbuf())), file_(false) {}  // line 7

    logstream(const std::string &filename) :
        os(new std::ofstream(filename)), file_(true)
    {
        // open file - raise exception if cannot open

    }

    std::ostream &operator<<(const std::string &s)
    {
        *os << s;
    }

    ~logstream()
    {
        // check if file and if so close
        if (file_)
        {
            dynamic_cast<std::ofstream*>(os.get())->close();
        }
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> os;
    bool file_;
};

int main()
{
    logstream l("test.txt");
    l << "some test"; // write to test.txt

    logstream another;
    another << "another test"; //write to std::cout by default
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, but it doesn't address the question: why use `logstream` in the first place, rather than use `std::ofstream` directly?  (There's also the small problem that you probably don't want to close `std::cout`.  An additional `if` in the destructor might be in order.)

Comment: I agree, I'd use `std::ofstream` from the very beginning. I don't think you close `std::cout`, as `file_` is `false` and the `if` line in the dtor doesn't execute.

Comment: I'd missed the boolean.  I've always done this a bit different: with an `std::ostream*`, which I could then test for `== &std::cout`.  (And there's no point in the `close` unless you're going to test the status of the stream after it.  Generally a good idea for an output stream, but logging is a bit of an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the constructor of the class you inherited from, `std::ostream`, on your initializer list.

Comment: Doesn't look like he needs to inherit from it in the first place.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Or if he inherits, he needs to provide his own `std::streambuf`.  (I usually combine the two: I don't inherit, but the `std::ostream` the wrapper points to does use a custom `streambuf`, e.g. to insert time stamp, file name and line number at the start of each line.)